# Write out the following equation as a power series

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, power-series

I am trying to write the following equation out as a power series:

$\frac{1}{x^{2}-3xn+3n^2}$

where $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x,n>0$. I have noticed that for $n=1$ we have

$\frac{1}{x^{2}-3xn+3n^2}=3+9x+24x^2+63x^3+...$

would there be a generalized formula for this expression as a power series in terms of $x$ and $n$?

Comment: I edited the question to look more reasonable.

Comment: Surely $\frac{1}{x^2-3x+3}$ should expand as $\frac13+\cdots$ (consider $x=0$).

Comment: You should still say: power series valid near $x=0$ or something.  General comments.  If you can factor the denominator, you can use partial fractions to get the sum of two geometric series.  Alternately, using "long division" you can write an order-$2$ recurrence for the coefficients of the power series.

Answer (score 1):

Following @GEdgar's suggestion and trying to combine everything to make it as compact as possible
$$\frac{1}{x^{2}-3xn+3n^2}=\sum_{p=0}^\infty a_p\,x^p$$ where
$$a_p=\frac{2^{p-1} }{3 \,n^{2 (p+1)}}\Bigg[\left(1+ i\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\frac{3-i \sqrt{3}}{12}  n\right)^p+\left(1- i\sqrt{3}\right)\left(\frac{3+i \sqrt{3}}{12}  n\right)^p \Bigg]$$  For $n=1$, the coefficients would be
$$\left\{\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{9},\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{27},0,-\frac{1}{81}
   ,-\frac{1}{81},-\frac{2}{243},-\frac{1}{243},-\frac{1}{729},\cdots\right\}$$

**Edit**  *(for more details)*

Write
$$\frac{1}{x^{2}-3xn+3n^2}=\frac 1 {(x-a)(x-b)}=\frac1{a-b}\left(\frac 1{x-a}-\frac 1{x-b} \right)$$ where
$$a=\frac{3-i \sqrt{3}}{2}  n\qquad \text{and} \qquad b=\frac{3+i \sqrt{3}}{2}  n$$ and use
$$\frac 1{x-c}=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {x^k}{c^{k+1}}$$

Comment: Could you expand on this a little bit? I am not entirely understanding where $\frac{2^{p-1}}{3n^{2(p+1)}}$ and the latter part come from. A step by step solution would really really help! Thanks.

Comment: @user931598. Details added